# How to transpose data from columns to rows, two columns at a time?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I am trying to transpose data from columns to rows, but only doing two columns at a time, across all rows. But skipping the first 2 columns.

My starting data frame looks like this:
Each row is a genetic marker. The first two columns give location information of that marker, the following columns provide DNA nucleotide information for individuals at that particular marker.

However, each individual has two nucleotides per marker.

Zeroes denote missing values.

So in this data frame there are 5 genetic markers on the row and a total of 3 individuals. (Individual 1 has both nucleotides defined in V1 and V2, Individual 2 has them in V3 and V4, and so on).

```
group pos V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
1     10  A  A  G  G  T  T
2     11  C  C  G  G  A  A
3     12  T  T  T  A  C  G
4     13  0  0  0  A  C  G
5     14  G  T  0  0  C  A
```

I want to reorder the data so that individuals are on the row and genetic marker on the column. However, I want to keep the "pairs" of nucleotides together and ignore the first two columns.

I want to out put this file:

```
A A C C T T 0 0 G T 
G G G G T A 0 A 0 0 
T T A A C G C G C A
```

So far, I've written a loop that works. But it is too slow, it can't really handle more than 40K rows. My data frames can be 500K rows and 130 columns.

```
oi2 <- list(NA) # create an empty list assigned to "oi2"
for(j in seq(3, ncol(data), 2)) { # create a sequence of data subset to keep 2 columns together 
oi <- "" # create an empty vector 
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)) { # do it for every row 
    oi <- c(oi, as.character(data[i,j]), as.character(data[i,j+1])) # add data together in a row 
  } # loop ends for row loop, were still inside first loop 
 oi <- oi[-1] # remove first "" element 
  oi2[[j-2]] <- oi # once oi is created, save to list "oi2", assigned to j-2 position in list 
} # loop closes 
oi3 <- oi2[!sapply(oi2, is.null)] # remove null elements in data frame 
# unlist the list and then convert to matrix, and then to data frame 
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(oi2), nrow=length(oi3), byrow=T, 
                          ncol = length(oi3[[1]])))
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this that would be faster and able to handle large data frames?

Comment: You should learn the Bioconductor packages such as `Biostrings` because they're much more efficient at manipulating big genetic data than base R.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but the best I could come up with at this hour (1AM)

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
dt <- fread("group pos V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
1     10  A  A  G  G  T  T
2     11  C  C  G  G  A  A
3     12  T  T  T  A  C  G
4     13  0  0  0  A  C  G
5     14  G  T  0  0  C  A", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**code**

```
library( tidyverse )
#paste together the rows of the dt (minus col 1 and 2)
l1 <- pmap( dt[, -c(1,2)], paste, sep = '')
#split the values in the list into pairs of 2 letters
l2 <- lapply( l1, strsplit, "(?<=.{2})", perl = TRUE )
#unlist
data <- unlist(l2)
#build a new matrix with three rows
matrix( data, nrow = 3) %>% apply( ., 1, paste, collapse = "")
```

**output**

```
#[1] "AACCTT00GT" "GGGGTA0A00" "TTAACGCGCA"
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Assuming the input `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end convert all but the first 2 columns to a 5x6 matrix and then reshape that into a 5x2x3 array, permute its dimensions and reshape back into a 3x10 matrix.  No packages are used.

```
m <- as.matrix(DF[-(1:2)]
nr <- nrow(m) # 5
nc <- ncol(m) # 6

matrix(aperm(array(m, c(nr, 2, nc/2)), c(3, 2, 1)), nc/2)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "C"  "C"  "T"  "T"  "0"  "0"  "G"  "T"  
[2,] "G"  "G"  "G"  "G"  "T"  "A"  "0"  "A"  "0"  "0"  
[3,] "T"  "T"  "A"  "A"  "C"  "G"  "C"  "G"  "C"  "A"
```

**2)** A variation of the above is to first transpose `m`, reshape it into an array and then permuate just the first two dimensions reshaping back to a matrix in the end.

```
matrix(aperm(array(t(m), c(2, nc/2, nr)), c(2, 1, 3)), nc/2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "C"  "C"  "T"  "T"  "0"  "0"  "G"  "T"  
[2,] "G"  "G"  "G"  "G"  "T"  "A"  "0"  "A"  "0"  "0"  
[3,] "T"  "T"  "A"  "A"  "C"  "G"  "C"  "G"  "C"  "A"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
group pos V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
1     10  A  A  G  G  T  T
2     11  C  C  G  G  A  A
3     12  T  T  T  A  C  G
4     13  0  0  0  A  C  G
5     14  G  T  0  0  C  A"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```